# Find $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{dx}{a+\sin{x}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Need to find A = $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{dx}{a+\sin{x}}$ for $|a| < 1$ by complex analysis.

It's easy to calculate it for $a > 1$. But the given case looks strange. First of all there will be a to bad points in denominator.

I've used a substitution: $z = \exp{i \phi}$ so we should get $A = 2 \pi \sum res_{z = z_{i}} f(z)$. But if there are two zeroes , then we should cut a small area around it , am I right?

Also I thought to consider integral as principle value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{ d\theta}{w - sin \theta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942086/integrating-int-pi-pi-frac-d-thetaw-sin-theta)

Comment: @user170231 no, there is no this case

Comment: Are you sure that both zeroes are inside the circumference?

Comment: @JoseManuelSanchezCuadrado yes , $\sin x = a$ has two solutions on circumference

Comment: @openspace but the zeroes you are looking for are the zeroes after making the variable change

Comment: @JoseManuelSanchezCuadrado there is a zeroes before substitution. And makes a some problem.

Comment: Just take one half of residue for each pole.

Comment: @user like a half of circumference?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @user so you guess that the result haven't changed ?

Comment: Comparing with?...

Comment: @user with $a>1$

Comment: With $a>1$ only one pole is inside the circle.

Comment: @clathratus maybe it exists only in v.p. meaning

Comment: Is $a$ complex-valued? If it is, take the known answer for $a > 1$ and construct the analytic continuation to $\mathbb C \backslash [-1, 1]$. If $a$ is real-valued, are you considering the improper integral in the p.v. sense? If not, the improper integral diverges (the integrand has a pole). The p.v. integral is zero.